# Combine bidimensional array with another single dimension array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine two arrays but keeping the keys with digit order.

Here's the first array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "nombre" => "Pilsener"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "nombre" => "Golden"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "nombre" => "Suprema"
  ]
]
```

And here's the other array:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "6"
  1 => "5"
  2 => "1"
]
```

What i want is:

```
    array:3 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "nombre" => "Pilsener"
        "cantidad" => "6"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "nombre" => "Golden"
        "cantidad" => "5"
      ]
      2 => array:1 [▼
        "nombre" => "Suprema"
        "cantidad" => "1"
      ]
    ]
```

I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554674/combining-arrays-but-keep-keys) but that didn't worked for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have strings as keys you can't use `array_merge_recursive()`, but you could loop through the array and look if the key also exists in the other array and add the array to the other array, e.g.

```
foreach($arr2 as $k => $v){
    if(isset($arr1[$k]))
        $arr1[$k] = $arr1[$k] + ["cantidad" => $v];
}
```

Comment: But, i would like an elegant way of doing it, i would use `array_combine`, but some names have spaces in the string, so i can't use them as key...

Comment: I've tried running this code and it doesn't work, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @GluePear Just forgot to remove the index. Read OP's array output wrong.

Comment: @JonathanS. I don't get what you mean

Comment: @Rizier123 - nice. JonathanS. - you should accept this answer. Much cleaner than my one.

Comment: It's a nice answer, but since the question is about how to combine, not how to access to the data i won't @GluePear

Comment: @JonathanS. It does combine your two arrays as you want to.

Comment: @JonathanS. Your question includes what you want the expected result to be, and Rizier's answer gives you that result. You should accept his answer or ask a new question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt watch it carefully, you're right @GluePear

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly elegant solution but it works:

```
$arr1 = [array('nombre'=>'Pilsener'),array('nombre'=>'Golden'),array('nombre'=>'Suprema')];
$arr2 = [6,5,1];

$new_array = [];

$i=0;

foreach($arr1 as $arr) {
    $temp_arr['nombre'] = $arr['nombre'];
    $arr['cantidad'] = $arr2[$i];
    $new_array[] = $arr;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Not bad, but i would prefer something shorter